# Is it possible to generate different random numbers faster than O(n)?

Tags: random, time-complexity

I have a range of numbers from 1-10 and I want to pick out 3 randomly but never the same twice. In lua I used a Fisher-Yates shuffle which is O(n), I know python has a built-in random.sample() also O(n). Can it be done faster with an arbitrary range and number of picks?

Comment: Tag a language, `random.sample` looks like Python

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to operate on any sequence of numbers where you read each one under complexity of O(n) because having n read operations alone puts it into linear complexity.

P.S.: This assumes that n is the number of picks. If you have an array and n is the size of that array and the number of picks m is constant, then you can generate a random index number with any method m times and achieve O(1), assuming array index takes constant time. I hope that answers your question, please clarify, if that didn't solve it.

Comment: Oh okay, I think I get it. So in this specific case, The FS-shuffle would be O(10) but I could do it in O(3)?